# How can i register multiple middleware permissions in routegroup?-Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I have 3 roles roles, admin, tutor and student.  i want to place them in 3 different goups, i however want the admin to be in all the groups. I have tried different methods to add the admin to other routes but it's not working. How can i make admin use all routes in tutor's middleware? Here is my code

**AdminMiddleware**, similar to all the others

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isRole()=="admin") {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

**routesmiddleware - in web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth'=>'admin']], function (){
   //admin routes
}
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth'=>'tutor']], function (){
//tutor routes
```

}

**in the Kernel.php**

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
'tutor' => \App\Http\Middleware\TutorMiddleware::class,
'student' => \App\Http\Middleware\StudentMiddleware::class,
```

**in user model**

```
public function isRole(){
    return $this->role; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is define a middleware that takes the supported roles as argument:

```
class HasRoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && in_array(Auth::user()->getRole(), $roles)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

This middleware expects that `User::getRole()` returns the role as string, i.e. `admin` or `tutor`. Then you need to define the middleware in `Kernel.php` as you have already done:

```
'any_role' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasRoleMiddleware::class,
```

And finally you can use the middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'any_role:admin'], function () {
        // admin routes
    }

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'any_role:admin,tutor'], function () {
       // tutor routes
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've also nested the route groups which perform role checks inside another route group which checks for authentication. This makes it more readable and reduces the risk you forget an authentication check in a future extension of your routes.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.