# How Can I Assign 2 Or More User Roles To 1 One Route In Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, roles, user-roles, laravel-authentication

I have user table with column role for user roles with `Enum` value:

**Migration**

```php
$table->enum('role', ['Admin','author','editor']);
```

What I want is, only **Admin** and **author** user Can Access to `site.com/view/problems` this page.

I have created 3 Middlewares on `\app\http\Middleware` with this content.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->role != 'Admin') {
        return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'Admin'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and put them into **Kernal.php**

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'Admin' =>\App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
        'author' =>\App\Http\Middleware\authorAdminMiddleware::class,
        'editor' =>\App\Http\Middleware\editorAdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

then used them in **web.php** like this

```php
Route::get('/view/problems', function () {
    //
})->middleware('Admin', 'editor');
```

But when I logged in with **Admin** user, It says you can access this page with **author** user.

And when I logged in with **author** user, it says you can access this page with **admin** user.

I want when I logged in with **Admin** or **author** user role, Can access this page. 
And when I logged in with **editor** can't access this page.

I have used **Middleware Groups** too. And it looks like before.

How can I do that ?

Comment: If I may ask, do you mean an admin **cannot** access editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i register multiple middleware permissions in routegroup?-Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548272/how-can-i-register-multiple-middleware-permissions-in-routegroup-laravel)

Comment: @Namoshek No sir , this isn't duplicate please attention to my question and answer and compare to that question and answer

Comment: It clearly is, please see the referenced answer. The solution there handles multiple roles.

Comment: My Problem Solved with @BharatGeleda Solution The link that you tell , it has getRole() that i don't know what is that and how can i define that! but on this answers it's clear and solved my problem after hours searching on stack and google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in multiple middlewares in the middleware() function, it requires that all the middlewares be run and passed. Now if the user does not have both the roles, it will fail.

One thing you could do is define a new Middleware which checks if the user is author or editor and lets it pass like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() && $request->user()->role != 'Admin' && $request->user()->role != 'author') {
            return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'Admin'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Another thing you can do is look into permissions i.e. assign particular permissions to both the roles. Say CanViewProblemsPermission and assign it to both the roles. You will require to implement that on your own or use a library like [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: your code not woked , i shoud test laravel permisson

Comment: I had by mistakenly used the `Author` instead of `author`. You can try with this. The general idea that both I and @oluwatobi have mentioned is the same and should work if done implemented correctly.

Comment: Yes Your Solution worked , sorry my mistake was in implementing this new middlware on kernel.php , another question if i want access a page for editor role i should define new middleware yes?

Comment: If it's a requirement which will repeat, I'd say look at the laravel-permission library. Having Roles and Permissions will be better and easier to modify later.

Comment: do you have any help(video or document) how to use laravel-permission package?

Comment: Their documentation seems quite extensive. You can have a look at https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the hierarchy of roles is in this order, 'Admin' -> 'author' -> 'editor'.

If the above is the case and then say,

- admin and author can see what editor can see,
- admin can see all,
- editor can only see editor's,
- author can see what belongs to himself and editor

Then your **author** middleware's `handle()` function may look like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() && in_array($request->user()->role, ['Admin','author'])) {

        return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', $request->user()->role));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

As you can see I checked for both 'author' and 'Admin' because 'Admin' is greater than author.